# BizTalk MQSeries adapter

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Looking to upgrade the BizTalk server to host on a windows 2008 R2 64 bit, but the WebSphere MQ stays in the 32 bit environment, would this be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't be a problem at all. You have one of two options:

1. On a 64-bit machine, mark the BizTalk Host that is assigned to run the MQSeries Adapter as a '32-bit only' host (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561079(v=bts.20).aspx). This will allow you to execute the adapter under a 32-bit architecture on a 64-bit machine under WOW64 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384249(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. Use a mixed 32-bit/64-bit environment - i.e. have one server in your BizTalk Group that is 32-bit and one (or more) that is 64-bit. Execute your MQSeries Adapter in a BizTalk Host configured with a Host Instance on the 32-bit server.

Note: The second option is probably overkill, but works well if you are upgrading to a 64-bit environment and slowly decommissioning older hardware.

Comment: Yup. Corrected. Thanks.